# JWPlayer Frame Number and Frame count

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jwplayer

I am using JW Player in an asp.net MVC application.  I can get the current position using:

```
jwplayer().getPosition()
```

However this not the frame number, any suggestions on how I can get the frame number; I need this to play frame by frame.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: jwplayer().getPosition() will return everything in regards to the # of seconds, not frames, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, I will convert sceonds to number then to frames based on the number of frames per second.

Comment: No problem, that is definitely one way to do it.